# Why are my MySQL results repeating unexpectedly?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have 3 database tables. 1 has details, 1 has features and 1 has hours. The feature and hours table have an id and an id from the the details table. What I am trying to do is create 1 array with 3 arrays in it, one for details, 1 for features and 1 for hours. Here is my code:

```
$query = mysqli_query($connection, "
SELECT `modelHomes`.`id`, 'testname' as `name`, `modelHomes`.`sqft`,
    '123 Fake St' as `address`, '555-5555' as `phone`, `modelHomes`.`galleryid`,
    `modelHomes`.`virtualtourid`, `modelHomeFeatures`.`text` as `feature`,
    `modelHomeHours`.`text` as `hour`
FROM `modelHomes`
INNER JOIN `modelHomeFeatures` ON `modelHomeFeatures`.`modelhomeid` = `modelHomes`.`id`
INNER JOIN `modelHomeHours` ON `modelHomeHours`.`modelhomeid` = `modelHomes`.`id`
");

                $results = array();
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){

                        $results[] = $row;

                }
                return $results;
```

it returns this:

> `Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [name] => testname [sqft] => 2501 [address] => 123 Fake St [phone] => 555-5555 [galleryid] => 9 [virtualtourid] => 1 [feature] => 4 Bedrooms [hour] => Mon-Thurs 1pm-6pm ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 1 [name] => testname [sqft] => 2501 [address] => 123 Fake St [phone] => 555-5555 [galleryid] => 9 [virtualtourid] => 1 [feature] => 4 Bedrooms [hour] => Friday 12pm-5pm ) [2] => Array ( [id] => 1 [name] => testname [sqft] => 2501 [address] => 123 Fake St [phone] => 555-5555 [galleryid] => 9 [virtualtourid] => 1 [feature] => 4 Bedrooms [hour] => Sat-Sun 12pm-5pm ) [3] => Array ( [id] => 1 [name] => testname [sqft] => 2501 [address] => 123 Fake St [phone] => 555-5555 [galleryid] => 9 [virtualtourid] => 1 [feature] => 2 Sided Gas Fireplace [hour] => Mon-Thurs 1pm-6pm ) [4] => Array ( [id] => 1 [name] => testname [sqft] => 2501 [address] => 123 Fake St [phone] => 555-5555 [galleryid] => 9 [virtualtourid] => 1 [feature] => 2 Sided Gas Fireplace [hour] => Friday 12pm-5pm ) [5] => Array ( [id] => 1 [name] => testname [sqft] => 2501 [address] => 123 Fake St [phone] => 555-5555 [galleryid] => 9 [virtualtourid] => 1 [feature] => 2 Sided Gas Fireplace [hour] => Sat-Sun 12pm-5pm ) [6] => Array ( [id] => 1 [name] => testname [sqft] => 2501 [address] => 123 Fake St [phone] => 555-5555 [galleryid] => 9 [virtualtourid] => 1 [feature] => All Oak Staircase with Open Risers [hour] => Mon-Thurs 1pm-6pm ) [7] => Array ( [id] => 1 [name] => testname [sqft] => 2501 [address] => 123 Fake St [phone] => 555-5555 [galleryid] => 9 [virtualtourid] => 1 [feature] => All Oak Staircase with Open Risers [hour] => Friday 12pm-5pm ) [8] => Array ( [id] => 1 [name] => testname [sqft] => 2501 [address] => 123 Fake St [phone] => 555-5555 [galleryid] => 9 [virtualtourid] => 1 [feature] => All Oak Staircase with Open Risers [hour] => Sat-Sun 12pm-5pm ) [9] => Array ( [id] => 1 [name] => testname [sqft] => 2501 [address] => 123 Fake St [phone] => 555-5555 [galleryid] => 9 [virtualtourid] => 1 [feature] => Upgraded Hardwood Flooring & Berber Carpet [hour] => Mon-Thurs 1pm-6pm ) [10] => Array ( [id] => 1 [name] => testname [sqft] => 2501 [address] => 123 Fake St [phone] => 555-5555 [galleryid] => 9 [virtualtourid] => 1 [feature] => Upgraded Hardwood Flooring & Berber Carpet [hour] => Friday 12pm-5pm ) [11] => Array ( [id] => 1 [name] => testname [sqft] => 2501 [address] => 123 Fake St [phone] => 555-5555 [galleryid] => 9 [virtualtourid] => 1 [feature] => Upgraded Hardwood Flooring & Berber Carpet [hour] => Sat-Sun 12pm-5pm ) [12] => Array ( [id] => 1 [name] => testname [sqft] => 2501 [address] => 123 Fake St [phone] => 555-5555 [galleryid] => 9 [virtualtourid] => 1 [feature] => Upgraded Ceramic Backsplash [hour] => Mon-Thurs 1pm-6pm ) [13] => Array ( [id] => 1 [name] => testname [sqft] => 2501 [address] => 123 Fake St [phone] => 555-5555 [galleryid] => 9 [virtualtourid] => 1 [feature] => Upgraded Ceramic Backsplash [hour] => Friday 12pm-5pm ) [14] => Array ( [id] => 1 [name] => testname [sqft] => 2501 [address] => 123 Fake St [phone] => 555-5555 [galleryid] => 9 [virtualtourid] => 1 [feature] => Upgraded Ceramic Backsplash [hour] => Sat-Sun 12pm-5pm ) [15] => Array ( [id] => 1 [name] => testname [sqft] => 2501 [address] => 123 Fake St [phone] => 555-5555 [galleryid] => 9 [virtualtourid] => 1 [feature] => 9' Main Floor Ceilings [hour] => Mon-Thurs 1pm-6pm ) [16] => Array ( [id] => 1 [name] => testname [sqft] => 2501 [address] => 123 Fake St [phone] => 555-5555 [galleryid] => 9 [virtualtourid] => 1 [feature] => 9' Main Floor Ceilings [hour] => Friday 12pm-5pm ) [17] => Array ( [id] => 1 [name] => testname [sqft] => 2501 [address] => 123 Fake St [phone] => 555-5555 [galleryid] => 9 [virtualtourid] => 1 [feature] => 9' Main Floor Ceilings [hour] => Sat-Sun 12pm-5pm ) [18] => Array ( [id] => 1 [name] => testname [sqft] => 2501 [address] => 123 Fake St [phone] => 555-5555 [galleryid] => 9 [virtualtourid] => 1 [feature] => Fruit Cellar Under Porch [hour] => Mon-Thurs 1pm-6pm ) [19] => Array ( [id] => 1 [name] => testname [sqft] => 2501 [address] => 123 Fake St [phone] => 555-5555 [galleryid] => 9 [virtualtourid] => 1 [feature] => Fruit Cellar Under Porch [hour] => Friday 12pm-5pm ) [20] => Array ( [id] => 1 [name] => testname [sqft] => 2501 [address] => 123 Fake St [phone] => 555-5555 [galleryid] => 9 [virtualtourid] => 1 [feature] => Fruit Cellar Under Porch [hour] => Sat-Sun 12pm-5pm ) [21] => Array ( [id] => 1 [name] => testname [sqft] => 2501 [address] => 123 Fake St [phone] => 555-5555 [galleryid] => 9 [virtualtourid] => 1 [feature] => Upgraded Wrap Around Porch [hour] => Mon-Thurs 1pm-6pm ) [22] => Array ( [id] => 1 [name] => testname [sqft] => 2501 [address] => 123 Fake St [phone] => 555-5555 [galleryid] => 9 [virtualtourid] => 1 [feature] => Upgraded Wrap Around Porch [hour] => Friday 12pm-5pm ) [23] => Array ( [id] => 1 [name] => testname [sqft] => 2501 [address] => 123 Fake St [phone] => 555-5555 [galleryid] => 9 [virtualtourid] => 1 [feature] => Upgraded Wrap Around Porch [hour] => Sat-Sun 12pm-5pm ) )`

I have no idea why results keep repeating. I have tried to adjust my code like so:

```
$results['hours'][] = $row['hour'];
$results['features'][] = $row['feature'];
$results['details'][] = $row;
```

but my results keep repeating also. This is the output I get:

```
Array ( [hours] => Array ( [0] => Mon-Thurs 1pm-6pm [1] => Friday 12pm-5pm [2] => Sat-Sun 12pm-5pm [3] => Mon-Thurs 1pm-6pm [4] => Friday 12pm-5pm [5] => Sat-Sun 12pm-5pm [6] => Mon-Thurs 1pm-6pm [7] => Friday 12pm-5pm [8] => Sat-Sun 12pm-5pm [9] => Mon-Thurs 1pm-6pm [10] => Friday 12pm-5pm [11] => Sat-Sun 12pm-5pm [12] => Mon-Thurs 1pm-6pm [13] => Friday 12pm-5pm [14] => Sat-Sun 12pm-5pm [15] => Mon-Thurs 1pm-6pm [16] => Friday 12pm-5pm [17] => Sat-Sun 12pm-5pm [18] => Mon-Thurs 1pm-6pm [19] => Friday 12pm-5pm [20] => Sat-Sun 12pm-5pm [21] => Mon-Thurs 1pm-6pm [22] => Friday 12pm-5pm [23] => Sat-Sun 12pm-5pm ) [features] => Array ( [0] => 4 Bedrooms [1] => 4 Bedrooms [2] => 4 Bedrooms [3] => 2 Sided Gas Fireplace [4] => 2 Sided Gas Fireplace [5] => 2 Sided Gas Fireplace [6] => All Oak Staircase with Open Risers [7] => All Oak Staircase with Open Risers [8] => All Oak Staircase with Open Risers [9] => Upgraded Hardwood Flooring & Berber Carpet [10] => Upgraded Hardwood Flooring & Berber Carpet [11] => Upgraded Hardwood Flooring & Berber Carpet [12] => Upgraded Ceramic Backsplash [13] => Upgraded Ceramic Backsplash [14] => Upgraded Ceramic Backsplash [15] => 9' Main Floor Ceilings [16] => 9' Main Floor Ceilings [17] => 9' Main Floor Ceilings [18] => Fruit Cellar Under Porch [19] => Fruit Cellar Under Porch [20] => Fruit Cellar Under Porch [21] => Upgraded Wrap Around Porch [22] => Upgraded Wrap Around Porch [23] => Upgraded Wrap Around Porch ) [details] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [name] => testname [sqft] => 2501 [address] => 123 Fake St [phone] => 555-5555 [galleryid] => 9 [virtualtourid] => 1 [feature] => 4 Bedrooms [hour] => Mon-Thurs 1pm-6pm ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 1 [name] => testname [sqft] => 2501 [address] => 123 Fake St [phone] => 555-5555 [galleryid] => 9 [virtualtourid] => 1 [feature] => 4 Bedrooms [hour] => Friday 12pm-5pm ) [2] => Array ( [id] => 1 [name] => testname [sqft] => 2501 [address] => 123 Fake St [phone] => 555-5555 [galleryid] => 9 [virtualtourid] => 1 [feature] => 4 Bedrooms [hour] => Sat-Sun 12pm-5pm ) [3] => Array ( [id] => 1 [name] => testname [sqft] => 2501 [address] => 123 Fake St [phone] => 555-5555 [galleryid] => 9 [virtualtourid] => 1 [feature] => 2 Sided Gas Fireplace [hour] => Mon-Thurs 1pm-6pm ) [4] => Array ( [id] => 1 [name] => testname [sqft] => 2501 [address] => 123 Fake St [phone] => 555-5555 [galleryid] => 9 [virtualtourid] => 1 [feature] => 2 Sided Gas Fireplace [hour] => Friday 12pm-5pm ) [5] => Array ( [id] => 1 [name] => testname [sqft] => 2501 [address] => 123 Fake St [phone] => 555-5555 [galleryid] => 9 [virtualtourid] => 1 [feature] => 2 Sided Gas Fireplace [hour] => Sat-Sun 12pm-5pm ) [6] => Array ( [id] => 1 [name] => testname [sqft] => 2501 [address] => 123 Fake St [phone] => 555-5555 [galleryid] => 9 [virtualtourid] => 1 [feature] => All Oak Staircase with Open Risers [hour] => Mon-Thurs 1pm-6pm ) [7] => Array ( [id] => 1 [name] => testname [sqft] => 2501 [address] => 123 Fake St [phone] => 555-5555 [galleryid] => 9 [virtualtourid] => 1 [feature] => All Oak Staircase with Open Risers [hour] => Friday 12pm-5pm ) [8] => Array ( [id] => 1 [name] => testname [sqft] => 2501 [address] => 123 Fake St [phone] => 555-5555 [galleryid] => 9 [virtualtourid] => 1 [feature] => All Oak Staircase with Open Risers [hour] => Sat-Sun 12pm-5pm ) [9] => Array ( [id] => 1 [name] => testname [sqft] => 2501 [address] => 123 Fake St [phone] => 555-5555 [galleryid] => 9 [virtualtourid] => 1 [feature] => Upgraded Hardwood Flooring & Berber Carpet [hour] => Mon-Thurs 1pm-6pm ) [10] => Array ( [id] => 1 [name] => testname [sqft] => 2501 [address] => 123 Fake St [phone] => 555-5555 [galleryid] => 9 [virtualtourid] => 1 [feature] => Upgraded Hardwood Flooring & Berber Carpet [hour] => Friday 12pm-5pm ) [11] => Array ( [id] => 1 [name] => testname [sqft] => 2501 [address] => 123 Fake St [phone] => 555-5555 [galleryid] => 9 [virtualtourid] => 1 [feature] => Upgraded Hardwood Flooring & Berber Carpet [hour] => Sat-Sun 12pm-5pm ) [12] => Array ( [id] => 1 [name] => testname [sqft] => 2501 [address] => 123 Fake St [phone] => 555-5555 [galleryid] => 9 [virtualtourid] => 1 [feature] => Upgraded Ceramic Backsplash [hour] => Mon-Thurs 1pm-6pm ) [13] => Array ( [id] => 1 [name] => testname [sqft] => 2501 [address] => 123 Fake St [phone] => 555-5555 [galleryid] => 9 [virtualtourid] => 1 [feature] => Upgraded Ceramic Backsplash [hour] => Friday 12pm-5pm ) [14] => Array ( [id] => 1 [name] => testname [sqft] => 2501 [address] => 123 Fake St [phone] => 555-5555 [galleryid] => 9 [virtualtourid] => 1 [feature] => Upgraded Ceramic Backsplash [hour] => Sat-Sun 12pm-5pm ) [15] => Array ( [id] => 1 [name] => testname [sqft] => 2501 [address] => 123 Fake St [phone] => 555-5555 [galleryid] => 9 [virtualtourid] => 1 [feature] => 9' Main Floor Ceilings [hour] => Mon-Thurs 1pm-6pm ) [16] => Array ( [id] => 1 [name] => testname [sqft] => 2501 [address] => 123 Fake St [phone] => 555-5555 [galleryid] => 9 [virtualtourid] => 1 [feature] => 9' Main Floor Ceilings [hour] => Friday 12pm-5pm ) [17] => Array ( [id] => 1 [name] => testname [sqft] => 2501 [address] => 123 Fake St [phone] => 555-5555 [galleryid] => 9 [virtualtourid] => 1 [feature] => 9' Main Floor Ceilings [hour] => Sat-Sun 12pm-5pm ) [18] => Array ( [id] => 1 [name] => testname [sqft] => 2501 [address] => 123 Fake St [phone] => 555-5555 [galleryid] => 9 [virtualtourid] => 1 [feature] => Fruit Cellar Under Porch [hour] => Mon-Thurs 1pm-6pm ) [19] => Array ( [id] => 1 [name] => testname [sqft] => 2501 [address] => 123 Fake St [phone] => 555-5555 [galleryid] => 9 [virtualtourid] => 1 [feature] => Fruit Cellar Under Porch [hour] => Friday 12pm-5pm ) [20] => Array ( [id] => 1 [name] => testname [sqft] => 2501 [address] => 123 Fake St [phone] => 555-5555 [galleryid] => 9 [virtualtourid] => 1 [feature] => Fruit Cellar Under Porch [hour] => Sat-Sun 12pm-5pm ) [21] => Array ( [id] => 1 [name] => testname [sqft] => 2501 [address] => 123 Fake St [phone] => 555-5555 [galleryid] => 9 [virtualtourid] => 1 [feature] => Upgraded Wrap Around Porch [hour] => Mon-Thurs 1pm-6pm ) [22] => Array ( [id] => 1 [name] => testname [sqft] => 2501 [address] => 123 Fake St [phone] => 555-5555 [galleryid] => 9 [virtualtourid] => 1 [feature] => Upgraded Wrap Around Porch [hour] => Friday 12pm-5pm ) [23] => Array ( [id] => 1 [name] => testname [sqft] => 2501 [address] => 123 Fake St [phone] => 555-5555 [galleryid] => 9 [virtualtourid] => 1 [feature] => Upgraded Wrap Around Porch [hour] => Sat-Sun 12pm-5pm ) ) )
```

How do I get the results into 3 arrays inside 1 array without data repeating?

These are the results I get when I enter the query into phpMyAdmin:

[image]

What I am looking for is 1 array with id, name, sqft, address, phone, galleryid and virtualtourid, 1 array with the features (no repeats) and 1 array with the hours (no repeats).

Comment: results are repeating because your query is returning repeated results. There's no way this code would push dupes into the array, unless the results had dupes to start with. Have you run that query manually and looked at what the results are?

Comment: yes I have run this query in phpmyadmin and my results are in my question in the form of a picture.

Comment: If you'd properly formatted your array dump, you'd see they're **NOT** repeating. the `hour` values are changing, exactly as they are in your screencap.

Comment: how would I properly format my array dump?

Comment: if you're dumping into a browser context, then `echo '<pre>';print_r($arr);echo '</pre>'` or dump into a content-type:text/plain area.

Comment: Yes please, if you can swap the output for formatted output, we'll more easily be able to see what data is coming out. You'll probably want to add some `ORDER BY` clauses to get them in a sensible order too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use group_concat to group the hours:

SELECT `modelHomes`.`id`, 'testname' as `name`, `modelHomes`.`sqft`,
    '123 Fake St' as `address`, '555-5555' as `phone`, `modelHomes`.`galleryid`,
    `modelHomes`.`virtualtourid`, `modelHomeFeatures`.`text` as `feature`,
    GROUP_CONCAT(`modelHomeHours`.`text`) as `hour`
FROM `modelHomes`
INNER JOIN `modelHomeFeatures` ON `modelHomeFeatures`.`modelhomeid` = `modelHomes`.`id`
INNER JOIN `modelHomeHours` ON `modelHomeHours`.`modelhomeid` = `modelHomes`.`id`
GROUP BY modelHomes.id

**TRY THIS**

```
$query = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT modelHomes.id, 'testname' as name, modelHomes.sqft,'123 Fake St' as address, '555-5555' as phone, modelHomes.galleryid,modelHomes.virtualtourid,
                                      modelHomeFeatures.text as feature,GROUP_CONCAT(modelHomeHours.text) as hour
                                     FROM modelHomes
                               INNER JOIN modelHomeFeatures ON modelHomeFeatures.modelhomeid = modelHomes.id
                               INNER JOIN modelHomeHours ON modelHomeHours.modelhomeid = modelHomes.id
                             GROUP BY modelHomes.id");
$results = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
    $ahours=explode(",",$row["hour"]);
    array_push($results,array(id=>$row["id"],
                              name=>$row["name"],
                              sqft=>$row["sqft"],
                              address=>$row["address"],
                              phone=>$row["phone"],
                              galleryid=>$row["galleryid"],
                              virtualtourid=>$row["virtualtourid"],
                              feature=>$row["feature"],
                              hour=>$ahours));
}
return $results;
```

**ANOTHER APROACH FOR THE QUERY**

```
    SELECT modelHomes.id, 'testname' as name, modelHomes.sqft,
           '123 Fake St' as address, '555-5555' as phone, 
           modelHomes.galleryid,modelHomes.virtualtourid,
           (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(modelHomeFeatures.text) 
              FROM modelHomeFeatures 
             WHERE modelHomeFeatures.modelhomeid = modelHomes.id) as feature,
           (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(modelHomeHours.text) 
              FROM modelHomeHours 
             WHERE modelHomeHours.modelhomeid = modelHomes.id) as hour
      FROM modelHomes
  GROUP BY modelHomes.id
```

Comment: that is not what I am looking for...I dont think my issue was with my query, I think its more on the php side and what I do with my results

Comment: my only issue is that when I GROUP_CONCAST(modelHomeFeatures.text) the features repeat itself

Comment: try the other aproach for the query